# concatenate rows and columns in a new sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, textjoin

I have sheet1 that looks like the following:

```
   A   B   C   D
1      7   8   9   
2  x
3  y
4  z
```

In sheet2 I want to concatenate to look like this:

```
   A
1  x | 7
2  y | 8
3  z | 9
```

I have tried:

```
=CONCATENATE(Sheet1!A2," | ",Sheet1!B$1)
```

but that gives me:

```
   A
1  x | 7
2  y | 7
3  z | 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=CONCAT(Sheet1!A2,"|", INDEX(Sheet1!B$1:D$1, , ROW(1:1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
=CONCATENATE(Sheet1!A2," | ",OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,ROW()))
```

or

```
=CONCATENATE(Sheet1!A2," | ",INDIRECT("Sheet1!" & ADDRESS(1,ROW()+1)))
```

***Note :*** Both `OFFSET` and `INDIRECT` are volatile functions. For details on volatile function see [this](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm).